# How to insert dot " . " after pressing space twice by softkeyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In `EditText` after pressing Space twice .

How can i get " `.` " dot in my `EditText`.

Condition:-

1-if `EditText` is empty " `.` " dot should not inserted.

2-if `EditText` contains some String only then "`.`" dot should inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for your EditText to keep watch on the input.

Inside, **`onTextChanged()`** method, you can do coding as you mentioned above.